# CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH don´t return highest resolution.

Tags: android, android-camera

**CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH:**

> Quality level corresponding to the highest available resolution.

```
CamcorderProfile qualityProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(numCam,CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
Toast.makeText(context, qualityProfile.videoFrameWidth + " x " + qualityProfile.videoFrameHeight , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This code return 640 x 480 for numCam = 0 and numCam = 1. Device have two cameras.

If I open device native app camera in app configuration I can see:

Back camera:

- 1280x720
- 640x480
- 320x240

Front camera:

- 640x480
- 320x240

¿Why I don´t get 1280x720 in code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is device specific bug (Galaxy tab 4).

I see device camera raw data and con´t contains avaliable video resolution key ("video-size-values")

Can check camera raw data [here in + info](http://www.android-database.com/#/detail/fe04cf6ed675838a)